# Maintain Row Selection in Pagination with Data which does not have any unique Id

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, onrowselection

**Aim**: Maintain Row Selection across the paginated data.

**Problem**: My data is not having any column which has unique data (for example id).

**Details**: I tried something like [LWC Datatable - Get the Row Number when editing a column](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316019/lwc-datatable-get-the-row-number-when-editing-a-column) but problem here is that I don't have any unique identifier for each row. One solution I can think of is that I'll add a unique identifier on each row(programmatically using some JS methods), but I don't want to change anything in existing data, so is there any better solution available? And if adding the unique identifier to each row is the only solution then what is the best possible way to do that?

**Note**: For table without pagination even the method given in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation as "**getSelectedName**" works even where there is no Id/unique data present in the table. When there is no pagination I'm able to get each and every row perfectly even when I'm selecting or deselecting the row. Problem is only with the pagination.

**EDIT**

Sample Data

`this.tableData = [{"fname":"FirstName","lname":"LastName","zipcode":sampleZipCodeNumber}]`

Sample Code

JS
`this.column = [{"label":"First Name","fieldName":"fname","type":"text"},{"label":"Last Name","fieldName":"lname","type":"text"},{"label":"ZIP Code","fieldName":"zipcode","type":"number"}]`

HTML
 `<lightning-datatable key-field={keyField} data={tableData} columns={columns} show-row-number-column={showRowNumberCol} hide-checkbox-column={hideRwSlctionChckbx} row-number-offset={rowNumberOffset} onrowselection={rwMthd}></lightning-datatable>`

Comment: are you able to share some code, specifically on what the data looks like (or make up something that is similar) along with the datatable html/js?

Comment: `code`this.tableData = [{"fname":"FirstName","lname":"LastName","zipcode":sampleZipCodeNumber}]
<br/><br/>
this.column = [{"label":"First Name","fieldName":"fname","type":"text"},{"label":"Last Name","fieldName":"lname","type":"text"},{"label":"ZIP Code","fieldName":"zipcode","type":"number"}]
<br/><br/>
<lightning-datatable 
     key-field={keyField}
     data={tableData}
     columns={columns}
     show-row-number-column={showRowNumberCol}
     hide-checkbox-column={hideRwSlctionChckbx}
     row-number-offset={rowNumberOffset}
     onrowselection={rwMthd}></lightning-datatable>`

Comment: FYI - You can [edit] your own post to include that information which makes it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* use a unique identifier in your data; this is required by LWC to efficiently update templates/virtual DOM elements, you will get odd/unpredictable behavior if you use a non-unique value. This can be as simple as assigning the index as a unique key:

```
this.data = this.data.map((value,index)=>({...value,index});
```

Where we use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to copy the data and add the index as another entry. You can then use that as the keyfield:

```
<lightning-datatable key-field="index" ...
```

Comment: then should I use the same new unique value in key-field parameter of the data table?

Comment: @user43598 Yes, you should.

Comment: In dataTable I have set 2 properties as
 `onrowselection={getSelectedName}  selected-rows={selectedRecordRows}`

I can see as soon as I click a checkbox "getSelectedName" is called and proper values gets set in "selectedRecordRows" (as per console.log), but on UI the checkbox is does not get checked for those selected records. 

If I remove ` selected-rows={selectedRecordRows}` then the dataTable shows the checkbox properly checked and also correct data in console. Here problem is, I have implemented pagination and when I traverse to different page the checkbox become blank on returning.

Comment: @user43598 LWC data binding is one-way, so you need to save/load the selected records before updating the page records, or you'll lose your selections.

Comment: can you please suggest then what is the best possible way to maintain the selections across the pages (meaning even when the page changes) and process the selected only as the last step?

Comment: Problem of the checkbox not getting selected on UI is resolved, it was a problem at my end.
Problem of checkbox not remaining persistent (on page change) is still there.....